# Does Google Analytics track the traffic of multiple domains?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website `subdomain.domain.com`. I created an analytics account for this and included the tracking code. Later I registered a new domain `xyz.com` and pointed to the same website `subdomain.domain.com`. **In Google analytics report, will the analytics display the traffic from both domains or do I need to make some alterations?**

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics tracks website traffic no matter what hostname is specified in the page URL. You can use the *Hostname* dimension in the content report to find out.
In your case, depending on the type of hostname redirection you may or may not see the *xyz.com* in your reports. When you navigate to the xyz.com in browser, pick any page and can see in your browser xyz.com - it will be tracked. If you can see subdomain.domain.com - the last will be tracked.

If you website is accessible via *subdomain.domain.com* and *xyz.com* - you may have an issue with cross-domain users and duplicated (inflated count of) users since GA cookie in a browser is set per hostname

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation where our URL has changed and we are now in a crossover period while both URLs are active.

Without changing the tracking code I am getting our stats as before **but** I cannot tell in the analytics reports which URL the visitor used to access the site. If that is not of concern to you then you don't need to update your tracking code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a secondary dimension under Content called "Hostname", this will break out your traffic by whether or not it was visited from `subdomain.domain.com` or `xyz.com`